# Add rel="lightbox" to every a tag including an image but not to those a tags that have a class="nothis", how to?

Tags: php, html, regex, lightbox

i use this code to add whenever into my page exist an a tag with img tag the rel="lightbox" as follow  :

```
$petropas1 = preg_replace('~<a(?=[^>]+>\s*<img)~','<a rel="lightbox"',$petropas1);
```

Till here it is okay but what about if i want to exclude the images that their a tag has an class="nothis" ? I mean, when exist this :

```
<a href="" class="nothis"><img src="" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a>
```

I want the regex i showed you before to add rel="lightbox" to every a tag before img but not to those that the a tag has the class="nothis".

Can you please tell me how to modify the regex in order to make this work ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead inside the positive lookahead to set the condition that match any but not of `class="nothis"`or `>` one or more times.

```
<a(?=(?:(?!class="nothis")[^>])+>\s*<img)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nR7cO4/4)

Comment: We have the solution is this one, thanks so much Avinash Raj !